# What is the API, given a user ID, to tell me permissions for a user of a list item ID?

Tags: permissions, rest, csom, api

I have an application that needs to be able to use my SharePoint API to check if a user `AD\USERNAME` has access to see a list item. I have the server relative URL of the list item, and the object identity.

I do *NOT* want to use the list item role assignments because this only has AD groups without their nested permissions. So I'd have to then access active directory which is a big pain.

I want similar to what this does:

[image: The check permissions feature is what I want]
[image: This is the feature I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling, found the answer embedded in another question [GetUserEffectivePermissions returns wrong results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128715/getusereffectivepermissions-returns-wrong-results) which is answered correctly.

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext("http://comtoso.com"))
{
     var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");
                ctx.Load(list);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     var permissions = list.GetUserEffectivePermissions(@"i:0#.w|domain\username");
     ctx.ExecuteQuery();

     foreach (var permission in Enum.GetValues(typeof(PermissionKind)).Cast<PermissionKind>())
     {
          var permissionName = Enum.GetName(typeof(PermissionKind), permission);
          var hasPermission = permissions.Value.Has(permission);
          Debug.WriteLine("Permission: {0}, HasPermission: {1}", permissionName, hasPermission);
     }
}
```

I also cross posted this question https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Sharepoint/en-US/98c6d208-b27a-4c8a-9789-067f0b16f690/what-is-the-api-given-a-user-id-to-tell-me-permissions-for-a-user-of-a-list-item-id?forum=sharepointdevelopment and there are some other alternatives supplied there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Get item level permission as described [here](https://www.morgantechspace.com/2017/09/get-item-level-permissions-sharepoint-csom.html) might help

Comment: Hi welcome to sharepoint stack exchange. My question states clearly that is not an option for me. I even explained why.